# Try ... Catching an Items.GetByName(SeekedName) vs expensive For Each Items.Item until CurrentItem.Name=SeekedName

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, try-catch, vsto

Under a VSTO/COM context, each call to the API (here Excel) is expensive (~1-10ms per call), mainly due to the marshalling involved in switching from managed to unmanaged code.

I have a spreadsheet with a large number of shapes, and need to get the reference of many given shapes, by their name. Some names will be called and there won't be any corresponding shape for them; this is completely fine, expected, and part of the business logic.

### Strategy 1

The Excel API exposes`ThisSheet.Shapes(ShapeName As String) as Excel.Shape` to get this shape, and returns an Exception if no shape relates to the given name: this is efficient on the COM side because it only takes one call. On the other hand, it requires a Try ... Catch and the burden of generating a stack trace when the shape does not exist, which may add up when many shapes are seeked and not found.

```
    Function TryGetFrom(ShapeName As String, Sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef FoundShape as Excel.Shape) As Boolean

        Try
            FoundShape = Sheet.Shapes.Item(ShapeName)
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function
```

### Strategy 2

An alternative is to loop through all the shapes in the sheet and exit the loop once `CurrentShape.Name = MyWantedShapeName`; if all shapes have been iterated and yet no shape complied, we know the shape we are looking for does not exist. This is great because it does not require any exception handling. Under most scenarios, this is the way I would go for, and most likely what most programmers would recommend doing. But iterating through each shape and calling the `CurrentShape.Name` for each of them requires many calls via COM, which is highly inefficient.

```
    Function TryGetFrom(ShapeName As String, Sheet As Excel.Worksheet, ByRef FoundShape as Excel.Shape) As Boolean

        For Each MyShape As Excel.Shape In Sheet.Shapes
            If MyShape.Name = ShapeName Then
                FoundShape = MyShape
                Return True
            End If
        Next

        Return False

    End Function
```

### Another alternative?

I understand there must be an optimum balance where depending on the number of shapes on the worksheet and the number of `ShapeName` mismatches, one strategy or the other should prevail. I am also aware I can accelerate the process by mapping all the shapes of the worksheet so that subsequent searches are faster (sample code has been simplified). I am wondering though, if there would be an intermediate alternative between the above two strategies, for example, would it be possible to catch exceptions without generating the stack trace? I would then be able to Try ... Catch (hence minimizing expensive COM calls), and yet avoid the expensive stack trace generations when `ShapeName` is a mismatch (I might not even need to know what the Exception is, knowing there was one would be sufficient for returning `False`).

I added the c# tag because it really should not matter what .Net language you use.

Comment: Strategy 1 is a no go. Using try/catch for control flow is bad.

Comment: @RoarS. In most cases I would agree, but here looping through all items takes a whooping 10-20 seconds, versus the few ms lost whilst Catching.. This is a very specific scenario here, have you read the details?

Comment: Yes, and if you want to do it that way, go for it, your code :-)

Comment: I'm looking for strategy 3 :)

Comment: How about adding VBA code to the Excel spreadsheet to cut out the repeated COM calls? [How to dynamically add and run a VBA macro from Visual Basic](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/219905/how-to-dynamically-add-and-run-a-vba-macro-from-visual-basic): "...it may be useful to move part of the code into a Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) module that can run inside the process space of the server. This can boost overall execution speed for your application..."

Comment: (You will, of course, use a better location for the .bas file than the root of drive C:.)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewMorton, unfortunately VBA is not an option for deployment. Ultimately, we might end up getting the XML of the Excel Workbook, but I was looking for improvement in the interim (interim means probably a year).

Comment: @HansPassant in our case Strategy 1 with 30 names sought over 30 shapes takes several seconds (with 70% of the processing coming from `Sheet.Shapes.Item(Name)`); Strategy 2 takes up to a minute (essentially making 30 + 29 + 28 + 27 + ... + 1 calls). What do you mean by packaging as an Excel add-in? Are you referring to XLL? We currently deploy the Add-in via VSTO + ClickOnce.

Comment: Any reason not to get ALL the shapes into an in memory collection eg List(Of Excel.Shape), then parse that rather than making multiple hits to the spreadsheet?